# Make thread loop for 5 iterations; pthreads, mutex, and semaphors

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, mutex, semaphore

I have this code in an example for my class, and the instructions from the teacher say to "make each thread loop for 5 iterations".  I am confused as to how to do that, wtih this code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <sys/utsname.h>

/* Symbolic Constants*/
#define NUM_THREADS 4
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10

/* Semaphore and Mutex lock */
sem_t cEmpty;
sem_t cFull;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

/* Threads */
pthread_t tid; /* Thread ID */
pthread_attr_t attr; /* Thread attributes */

//prototypes
void *producer(void *param);
void *consumer(void *param);
int insert_item(int threadID);
int remove_item(int threadID);
void init();

/* Progress Counter and Thread IDs*/
int counter, pthreadID=0, cthreadID=0;

int main()
{
  /* Variables */
  int c1;

  /* Perform initialization */
  init();

  /* Create the producer threads */
  for(c1=0; c1<NUM_THREADS; c1++)
  {
    pthread_create(&tid, &attr, producer, NULL);
  }

  /* Create the consumer threads */
  for(c1=0; c1<NUM_THREADS; c1++)
  {
    pthread_create(&tid, &attr, consumer, NULL);
  }

  /* Ending it */
  sleep(2);

  printf("All threads are done.\n");

  /* Destroy the mutex and semaphors */
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
  sem_destroy(&cEmpty);
  sem_destroy(&cFull);

  printf("Resources cleaned up.\n");

  exit(0);
}

void init()
{
  pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL); /* Initialize mutex lock */
  pthread_attr_init(&attr); /* Initialize pthread attributes to default */
  sem_init(&cFull, 0, 0); /* Initialize full semaphore */
  sem_init(&cEmpty, 0, BUFFER_SIZE); /* Initialize empty semaphore */
  counter = 0; /* Initialize global counter */
}

void *producer(void *param)
{
  int x;
  for(x=0; x<5;)
  {
    sleep(1);

    sem_wait(&cEmpty); /* Lock empty semaphore if not zero */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    if(insert_item(pthreadID))
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Producer error.");
    }
    else
    {
      pthreadID++;
      x++;
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_post(&cFull); /* Increment semaphore for # of full */
  }
return 0;
}

void *consumer(void *param)
{
  int y;
  for(y=0; y<5;)
  {
    sleep(1);

    sem_wait(&cFull); /* Lock empty semaphore if not zero */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    if(remove_item(cthreadID))
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Consumer error.");
    }
    else
    {
      cthreadID++;
      y++;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_post(&cEmpty); /* Increments semaphore for # of empty */
  }
return 0;
}

int insert_item(int threadID)
{
  if(counter < BUFFER_SIZE) /* Buffer has space */
  {
    counter++;
    printf("Producer %d inserted a cookie. Total:%d\n", threadID, counter);
    return 0;
  }
  else /* Buffer full */
  {
    return -1;
  }
}

int remove_item(int threadID)
{
  if(counter > 0) /* Buffer has something in it */
  {
    counter--;
    printf("Consumer %d removed a cookie. Total:%d\n", threadID, counter);
    return 0;
  }
  else /* Buffer empty */
  {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Anyone have any idea of where I add my for loop to "make each thread loop for 5 iterations"? Thank you so much in advanced.

UPDATE:  I changed the while(1) to a for loop with 5 iterations, but I still cant get the messages from the insert_item and remove_item functions to print 5 times, the only print once.  Anyone know how I can get it to print 5 times?

Comment: 1. Google for "producer-consumer model with pthreads" Like this - http://cs.gmu.edu/~white/CS571/Examples/pthread_examples.html. 2. Adapt the code for your needs. 3. (optionally) Learn something from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that at the end of main, I call sleep(2).  This is not enough time for all of the threads to print their output.  I was also not passing the right index to my add_item and remove_item functions.  In addition, I needed a join command for all of the threads rather than the sleep command, and the join command ensures that all of the threads finish before the program exits. Here is the updated and corrected code.  Hope this helps someone trying to do something similar!

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <sys/utsname.h>

// Symbolic Constants
#define NUM_THREADS 4
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10

// Semaphore and Mutex lock
sem_t cEmpty;
sem_t cFull;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

// Threads
pthread_t tid[NUM_THREADS]; //Thread ID
pthread_t tid2[NUM_THREADS]; //Thread ID
pthread_attr_t attr; //Thread attributes

//prototypes
void *producer(void *param);
void *consumer(void *param);
int insert_item(long threadID);
int remove_item(long threadID);
void init();

//Progress Counter and Thread IDs
int counter=0;

int main()
{
  //Variables
  long c1;

  //Perform initialization
  init();

  //Create the producer threads
  for(c1=0; c1<NUM_THREADS; c1++)
  {
    pthread_create(&tid[c1], &attr, producer, (void *)c1);
    pthread_create(&tid2[c1], &attr, consumer, (void *)c1);
  }

  //Ending it
  for(c1=0; c1<NUM_THREADS; c1++)
  {
    pthread_join(tid[c1], NULL);
    pthread_join(tid2[c1],NULL);
  }

  printf("All threads are done.\n");

  //Destroy the mutex and semaphors
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
  sem_destroy(&cEmpty);
  sem_destroy(&cFull);

  printf("Resources cleaned up.\n");

  exit(0);
}

//This function performs initialization
void init()
{
  pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL); //Initialize mutex lock
  pthread_attr_init(&attr); //Initialize pthread attributes to default
  sem_init(&cFull, 0, 0); //Initialize full semaphore
  sem_init(&cEmpty, 0, BUFFER_SIZE); //Initialize empty semaphore
  counter = 0; //Initialize global counter
}

//This function creates the producer thread
void *producer(void *param)
{
  long index = (long)param;

  for(int x = 0; x<5; x++)
  {
    sleep(1);

    sem_wait(&cEmpty); //Lock empty semaphore if not zero
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    //check to see if item inserted correctly; print error on fail
    if(insert_item(index))
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Producer error.");
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_post(&cFull); //Increment semaphore for # of full
  }
pthread_exit(NULL);
return 0;
}

//This function created the consumer thread
void *consumer(void *param)
{
  long index = (long)param;

  for(int x = 0; x<5; x++)
  {
    sleep(1);

    sem_wait(&cFull); //Lock empty semaphore if not zero
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    //print error if cookie not decremented correctly
    if(remove_item(index))
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Consumer error.");
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_post(&cEmpty); //Increments semaphore for # of empty
  }
pthread_exit(NULL);
return 0;
}
//Insert item function to increment the cookie count and print thread message
int insert_item(long threadID)
{
  if(counter < BUFFER_SIZE) //Buffer has space
  {
    counter++;
    printf("Producer %ld inserted a cookie. Total:%d\n", threadID, counter);
    return 0;
  }
  else //Buffer full
  {
    return -1;
  }
}

//Remove item function to decrement the cookie count and print thread message
int remove_item(long threadID)
{
  if(counter > 0) //Buffer has something in it
  {
    counter--;
    printf("Consumer %ld removed a cookie. Total:%d\n", threadID, counter);
    return 0;
  }
  else //Buffer empty
  {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry about the formatting, I am not sure why it isn't recognizing any of my spaces and tabs and line breaks.....